# How can I move 1 row down while maintaining the end of the range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

First of all let me say I am really impressed with all the knowledge about excel that rests in these posts.
Second, I have a problem and I thought that you maybe will be able to help me.
I am building a "calculator" as I have a matrix of 3799x3799 and Solver is not able to process what I want.
The problem is that I use this formula,

> {=MIN(ABS(F10:F3799-$C$2))}

in a row, and when I expand it, it goes like this :

> {=MIN(ABS(G10:G3799-$C$2))}

when in fact I want it to be G11 not G10 (as my matrix is the lower half of the matrix only).
How can I do that happen? Without changing it by hand and without using VBA (as my file is already very demanding and with VBA my excel will crush).

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`=MIN(ABS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN()+1,ROW()+1,1,1)):G3799-$C$2))`

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Change addition to `COLUMN()` and `ROW()` as per your data location in excel

Comment: Thank you both! A friend suggested me an OFFSET function and it worked. Either way, I will use yours for further calculations so, thanks!